# How to replace Feature Name have Unit word by Unit Only After as Keyword?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I work with SQL Server 2012 and face an issue: I can't replace Features contain  Unit word to be Unit only.

So this code returns

```
'FamilyUnit' as [FamilyUnit]
```

while I need it to be

```
 'FamilyUnit' as [Unit]
```

Meaning word after as keyword if it contains `Unit`, then it should be `Unit` only.

Change will be after the `AS` keyword.

```
create table #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal
(
     DKFeatureName nvarchar(100),
     DisplayOrder int
)

insert into #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal (DKFeatureName, DisplayOrder)
values ('package', 1), ('packageUnit', 1),
       ('Family', 2), ('FamilyUnit', 2),
       ('parts', 3), ('partsUnit', 3)

DECLARE @Header nvarchar(max) =  
    (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ''' + DKFeatureName + ''' AS ['+ DKFeatureName +']' AS [text()]
     FROM #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal 
     GROUP BY DKFeatureName
     ORDER BY MIN(DisplayOrder)
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 10000) [Columns])

PRINT @Header
```

Expected result is to replace all words that contain `Unit` with just `Unit` only, so the output should be:

```
 'package' as [package], 
 'packageUnit' as [Unit], 
 'Family' as [Family], 
 'FamilyUnit' as [Unit],  
 'parts' as [parts], 
 'partsUnit' as [Unit]
```

Comment: thank you for reply if i need to change also before as what I do please

Comment: meaning as sample 'packageUnit' as [Unit] I need it to be 'Unit' as [Unit] so how to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CASE` expression:

```
DECLARE @Header nvarchar(max) =  
    (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ''' + DKFeatureName + ''' AS '
        + QUOTENAME(CASE WHEN DKFeatureName LIKE '%Unit' THEN 'Unit' ELSE DKFeatureName END) AS [text()]
     FROM #SplitNumberAndUnitsFinal 
     GROUP BY DKFeatureName
     ORDER BY MIN(DisplayOrder)
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 2, 10000) [Columns])
```

For quoting identifiers is safer to use `QUOTENAME` function instead of adding `[]`

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f797e769b8245f02e9105e15e7328ed)**

Comment: only this modification part before as where it contain Unit not changed

Comment: @aboelham The you could use the same CASE expression without QUOTENAME instead of first DKFeatureName - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=37a310b38576f77b718e90c8e7228ac5